# How to shift integers by 1 but maintaining the same range?

Tags: r, sequence, shift, rep

Without using the `c()` function, I need to reproduce the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

I have this for now but it does only repeat `1:5` 5 times, while I need every repetition to be shifted 1 number

```
rep(seq(1, 5),5)  
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
1:5 + rep(0:4, each=5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

or using `mapply`.

```
as.vector(mapply(`+`, list(1:5), 0:4))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Or `sequence(rep(5, 5), 1:5)`.